# Chess Engine Debug Assertion Failed while trying to go to depth

Tags: c++, debugging

So I am making a Chess Engine:

```
#include <vector>
#include "ChessBoard.h"

std::vector<ChessBoard> generatePositionsToDepth(const ChessBoard& initialBoard, int depth) {
    std::vector<std::vector<ChessBoard>> positions(depth + 1);
    positions[0].push_back(initialBoard);

    for (int d = 1; d <= depth; d++) {
        for (const ChessBoard& board : positions[d - 1]) {
            ChessBoard boardCopy = board;
            boardCopy.generateMoves(); // Generate moves makes a vector with all the new positions as ChessBoard classes
            const std::vector<ChessBoard>& newPositions = boardCopy.getPositions(); // And getPositions returns the vector
            positions[d].insert(positions[d].end(), newPositions.begin(), newPositions.end());
        }
    }

    return positions[depth];
}
```

I've done the move generation and when I try to calculate depth it goes only up to 3.

If I go up to 4 it throws [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgC8x.png) error:

```
Debug Assertion Failed!
Program: ...sies\MyProjects\ByteChess\ByteChess\x64\Debug\ChessEngine.exe
File: minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\convert\isctype.cpp
Line: 36
Expression: c >= -1 && c <= 255
```

Comment: What tool chain are you using? What platform are you on? Any complete development environment will includea debuger which should tell you where the error happens.

Comment: What happens when you hit "Retry" to debug the application?

Comment: What you need to do is debug the application, examine the *stack trace* that will tell you where in **your code** that this error originates. That's the first step, then take it from there. Learning how to debug is just about the most important practical skill you will ever learn as a programmer.

Comment: Visual Studio has a very good debugger, so here is when you learn how to use it.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I am using Visual Studio but it doesn't point to any line, it just throws the error.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it throws the same error again and again

Comment: The popup tells you to “Press Retry to debug the application”. Did you do that? What happened?

Comment: @PeteBecker Before nothing happened, Now it took me to this function

`
bool ChessBoard::sameColor(char piece1, char piece2) {
 return (isupper(piece1) && isupper(piece2)) || (islower(piece1) && islower(piece2));
}
`
I represent each piece as a char and uppercase is white and lower is black, I use this function quite often and for up to depth 3, there doesn't seem to be any problem

Comment: Look at the values of the variables in the line that the debugger took you to. Make sure the values look valid.

Comment: There is a check in debug mode when you call `std::isupper()` and `std::islower()` to ensure the values you are giving it are actually characters that can be used in those functions.

Comment: @drescherjm The thing is that the function works fine up to a certain depth, after a while it throws the error

Comment: @Koulhs035 The error message states what is wrong.  Also, the code you posted is not calling `sameColor` anywhere, unless `generateMoves` is calling this function.

Comment: ***The thing is that the function works fine up to a certain depth, after a while it throws the error*** Does not mean anything. The values could be bad because of a bug in this function or some other part of your code. Your debugger says the values are bad and you should investigate to see if you can determine the reason. Also you can use the call stack to back up and attempt to see where the values got corrupted.

Comment: *so I don't know much about debugging stuff like this* -- Debugging is part and parcel of learning how to write programs.  You can't simply just write a program, see that it doesn't work, and then not know what to do if there is a bug.  It doesn't matter how much time you spent on writing the original program, debugging is a mandatory step that must be learned.  The debugger that comes with Visual C++ is one of the best out there, and in your case, it is pointing exactly to where the issue is.  There was no need to go to ChatGPT at all initially.

Comment: *I represent each piece as a char and uppercase is white and lower is black,* -- Then more than likely you forgot to initialize one or more of those pieces, and those pieces have garbage values that you are calling `isupper()` and `islower()` on.  The `assert` is basically saying "the values you are giving me are nonsense".

Comment: And @PaulMcKenzie last comment is the reason why you need to look at the variables to determine were and how the bad values creeped into your data. If they were bad in sameColor() are they bad in the function that calls it? Are you accessing some vector out of bounds to get the color values?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie But wouldn't the problem appear earlier? Why when I go to depth 6 and not earlier?

Comment: ***But wouldn't the problem appear earlier?*** Because unfortunately with undefined behavior a bug may produce results that look correct some of the time. This is the worst behavior of UB.

Comment: @Koulhs035 *But wouldn't the problem appear earlier?* -- First, you need to remove this line of thinking when you are debugging code.   Thinking this way will tend to make programmers *not* consider the various possibilities that could have occurred.  The job is to simply debug the code, and that is when you get the "so that's what happened!" moment.  Second, uninitialized values can be anything, including "good" values that "worked".

Comment: Read [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub (especially all the excellent articles linked at the end).

Answer (score -1):

You program called function `isupper(int c)` with wrong  parameter. Most often error is to pass char as first parameter. Char must be casted to unsigned char:

```
isupper(static_cast<unsigned char>(c))
```

Your code does not have it, but some underlying function called it and assert is called in Debug mode( in Release mode - ignores it and creates undefined behaviour). You can press Retry, go to Debugger, click to Stack window in MSVC IDE, click functions in stack step by step and find the call of this function. This call must be fixed.

It is one of often mistakes to call `isspace()`, `islower()`, `isupper()` with char as first parameter.

isupper( int c) expects only integer parameter -1 (EOF) or 0..255. If you pass char parameter to isupper, then all char values from -127 to -2 are casted to int -127..-2, what is wrong and cause assert in Debug mode of library. All values that are not from range -1..255 generate undefined behaviour (random returned value, access of wrong or nonexistent memory, segmentation fault etc). Check ALL isupper() calls in your program.

Comment: I found from the call stack that the problem is indeed a function that contains isupper( ). However I'm not sure how to fix this since the function is pretty straight forward, it's just called a lot of times.

The function in question:

`
bool ChessBoard::sameColor(char piece1, char piece2) {
    return (!(isupper(piece1) ^ isupper(piece2)));
}
`

Comment: What values do `piece1`  and `piece2` contain when the function asserts? Do these look valid? If they are not valid go up the callstack and determine where they got bad values.

Comment: @drescherjm Whenever this function is called, I put a character inside, I've double checked everything. My suspicion has started to shift towards the vector that I've saved everything in, There are a lot of instances of the chessboard, thousands maybe. And I think it it's getting out of bounds somewhere

EDIT: I think that's why the problem appears after a certain depth

Comment: That is why you need to use your debugger. It's highly unlikely for you to figure this out without debugging. And we really can not help you because we don't have the code. And for me I am on the clock and need to get back to debugging a 200 thousand line program.

Comment: *Whenever this function is called, I put a character inside, I've double checked everything.* -- Obviously things were not checked sufficiently -- the debugger proves this.  An automated tool is not going to miss things like this, whereas a human being could easily not see everything that is being done, thus believe things have been "checked".

Comment: @Koulhs035 It is exactly place with error. Just change to correct call of isupper():  isupper(static_cast<unsigned char>(piece1)) ^ isupper(static_cast<unsigned char>(piece2)) . It is documented in the documentation of isupper(). Also check all calls of isupper() in your program.